# How to update the URL in "then*" function?

Tags: javascript, casperjs

I have below code snippet.

```
var admin_url = "http://www.sampledomain.com/";
var casper = require('casper').create();
casper.start();

casper.thenOpen(
    "http://www.test.com", {
        method: "post",
        data: {
            param1: "some data"
        }
    },
    function() {
        what_i_want = this.getPageContent().split("[")[1].split("]")[0]
        admin_url += what_i_want;
    }
);

casper.thenOpen(admin_url, function() {
    this.echo(this.getCurrentUrl());
});

casper.run();
```

I first post to http://www.test.com, then use the returned data, I try to modify the admin_url, which is my second URL that need to access. However, my testing shows that the second `thenOpen` method still got the old `admin_url` value and did not pick up the latest updated value (notice that I've updated it in the first `thenOpen` method). What's the reason of this issue and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `thenOpen` the `admin_url` is passed by value, but `thenOpen` itself is executed asynchronously. You can see it this way: You add some steps to the queue and when you call `run`, the queue begins to execute with the initial steps and their accompanying data. So you need to add your last `thenOpen` step dynamically to the queue when the `admin_url` is complete:

```
casper.thenOpen(
    "http://www.test.com", {
        method: "post",
        data: {
            param1: "some data"
        }
    }, function then() {
        whatIWant = this.getPageContent().split("[")[1].split("]")[0]
        admin_url += video_id;

        this.thenOpen(admin_url, function() {
            this.echo(this.getCurrentUrl());
        });
    }
);

casper.run();
```

There is also the possiblity to break `thenOpen` into its sub-functions and use `admin_url` as a global variable:

```
var admin_url = "...";
casper.thenOpen(
    "http://www.test.com", {
        method: "post",
        data: {
            param1: "some data"
        }
    },
    function() {
        what_i_want = this.getPageContent().split("[")[1].split("]")[0]
        admin_url += what_i_want;
    }
).then(function() {
    this.open(admin_url);
}).then(function() {
    this.echo(this.getCurrentUrl());
}).run();
```

It reduces the nesting which might be a good thing based on your preference.

Comment: Thanks again Artjom. This solution is exactly what I've taken.

Comment: I added an alternative approach as a real global variable.