# Next page doesn't load when it should be opened from a previously set variable

Tags: javascript, casperjs

I am parsing out a url from `href` attribute, but when I do

```
casper.thenOpen(url, function() {
    this.echo(this.getCurrentUrl());
});
```

shows a blank.

The link on my webpage that I am trying to access is opened in a new tab and it is slightly more complicated to test a new tab using casper than just navigating to a new link on the same tab (I think so) which is why I am getting the link in a variable and then trying to open it.

Am I missing something here?

Code snippet:

```
var href = '';

casper.then(function() {
    this.test.assertExists(x('//a[contains(@href, "SUBSTRING OF URL")]'), 'the element exists');
    href = casper.getElementAttribute(x('//a[contains(@href, "SUBSTRING OF URL")]'), 'href');
});

casper.thenOpen(href, function() {
    this.echo(getCurrentUrl());
});
```

So when I echo `href`, its value is the same as the url I want to navigate to. But `getCurrentUrl` shows `about:blank`. Also, the URL opens up in less than a second, but it times out after 5000ms when I tried `casper.waitForUrl()`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to update the URL in "then\*" function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26539629/how-to-update-the-url-in-then-function)

Comment: Thanks Artjom. I will try that out.

Comment: It did work, getCurrentUrl() shows the correct url. But taking a screenshot shows a blank picture though. Again is there something I am missing ? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Could be a number of things. You should investigate and ask a new question when you do. To help you before you [post a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), please register to the [`resource.error`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#resource-error), [`casper.page.onResourceTimeout`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-resource-timeout.html), [`remote.message`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#remote-message) and [`page.error`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#page-error) events. Maybe there are errors.

Comment: Alright. Thanks for your earlier efforts in helping others as well as I found them useful :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Casper works by pushing all your requests on to a stack, then running them. So at the point you call this:

```
casper.thenOpen(href, function() {
    this.echo(getCurrentUrl());
});
```

`href` has not had chance to be defined yet. I believe the following refactor is one way to fix it:

```
casper.then(function() {
  casper.open(href,function(){
    this.echo("Did it work this time?");
    });
});
```

Comment: (Sorry, I only just looked at the suggested duplicate, and I see my answer is basically the same as the one posted there!)

Comment: Thank you. I have another question; the url contains an rss feed and I need to parse some information out for my test. Would this be  inside the casper.open( .... ) block ?

Comment: It could be. But what I would normally do is, after the above `casper.then` is add `casper.waitForSelector('...', function(){});` where the `...` is something you expect to only see, and the function is how you want to deal with it.
That avoids lots of nested functions, but also avoids bugs caused by trying to process pages that are still loading.

Comment: That makes sense. My code is very similar to what the suggested duplicate has (second alternative, the one with no nesting). Outside the then function where I get current url, I am trying to see what the url is and it shows blank. I am not navigating to any other page after that. Why is this happening ?

Comment: Please let me know if this is not clear and I will add the piece of code for clarity.

Comment: "Outside the then function" means in global scope? Remember global scope is where you give casper all the instructions, but nothing happens until the end of your script when you tell it to run. In other words, always remember that at the end of your script the first page has not been loaded yet. Everything you do has to be done inside the callbacks.
(I don't mean "global scope" strictly there; it might all be done inside another function, for tidiness. The key point is that the call to `run` starts everything going.)

Comment: Ahh I see. Thank you. That helped. Can't vote up, need 15 reputation points. Never really ask/answer questions on SO. Need to be more active as I just started working :)